# Generate all combinations for variables and insert into temp table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have one requirement there are 4 variables and i want all combinations of 4 variables and insert into temp table .

```
DECLARE StartDateTime DATETIME;
DECLARE Age INT; 
DECLARE Duration INT ;
DECLARE TotalDD INT;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable(
    Duration INT,
    TotalDD INT,
    Age INT,
    StartDateTime DATETIME,
   
);
SET Age = 16;
SET TotalDD = 14;
SET Duration = 30;
SET StartDateTime = CURDATE();
```

Excepted Result:

```
Duration age TotalDD StartDateTime
30 null null null
null 16 null null
30 null null null
30 16 null null
null null 14 20200622
30 null 14 null
30 16 null 20200622
```

...........
..........
so on

please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `cross join`:

```
select *
from (select 16 as age union all select null) a cross join
     (select 14 as totaldd union all select null) t cross join
     (select 30 as duration union all select null) d cross join
     (select CURDATE() as StartDateTime union all select null) s
```